# Wordpress Template CSS issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have modified a website template so that the colour has changed.

The Wordpress template uses .less files as default settings for the admin panel so when changing settings and saving from the console the style.css file is rewritten.

I modified the style.css file and use that as I couldn't find all of the CSS code in the .less files.

After changing the colours in the style.css file some of the active items change colour on mouse roll on or off and change to white which result on disappearing on a white background. Problem is I can't find the location in the code to change these!!

Have attempted examining elements in browser, following file locations and names, searching by colour codes too.

What is the best way to find them?

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide us a link to your website?

Comment: So it's just the css of the magnifying glass search box and in the contact page the send and clear buttons... I was asked to help with it and couldn't figure these bits out!

Comment: you would need to change the css for `.btn` then. try adding it into a custom css inside the template settings page and add `!important` to the rules you would like to apply.

Comment: Thank you, will that cover the magnifying glass too? 
Googling !important now as well!

Comment: yep, the magnifying glass is also with class `.btn`

Comment: further infos about !important at smashing magazine - http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: Thank you! How do I up vote you from comments?!

Comment: left from the comment, but i create an answer ok?

Comment: Some themes allow you to customize colors in the theme's settings. It's where I would check first.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have & there are no options there. They are all pre defined in the files

Comment: The fact you have .less files means you should be running a pre-processor, edit the less files, then the style.css file is updated for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would need to change the css for `.btn` then. try adding it into a custom css inside the template settings page and add `!important` to the rules you would like to apply.

The magnifying glass is also with class `.btn` so it would work for all of your buttons.

i guess you don't want the `border-bottom: red` property!

Comment: tried adding this to the main css file - .btn {color:#6E70A3 !important;} though it hasn't worked...

Comment: Avoid !important if you can. Use overriding classes instead that you load after the original ones.